# How to remove duplicate function

Tags: powershell

I'm new at working with Powershell (Version 4.0).

I created different modules:

```
My-Modules  
My-Tools  
My-HelpfullCommands
```

In each module directory I have the .psd1 file where I set the `FunctionsToExport='My-*'` . In the same directory is a .psm1 file with different functions in it.

For Example in the "My-Modules.psm1":

```
My-GetAvailabilityGroup
My-LastSqlBackup  
New-SMOConnection
```

And in the "My-Tools.psm1":

```
My-BackupRestoreFromAg
My-GetDbSize
New-SMOConnection
```

When I check the available commands with `Get-Command -Name My-*` I find the expected 4 commands.

BUT: When I check `Get-Command -Name *SMO*`I find the `New-SMOConnection` two times. Once from the module My-Tools and once from the module My-Modules.

When I try to execute the `New-SMOConnection` I get the error message `New-SMOconnection : The term 'New-SMOconnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...` (you know the ObjectNotFound message ;-) )

So, my question is:
Is it possible to "remove" the `New-SMOConnection` functions, so that they are not visible anymore?

Another question:
Why do the `New-SMOConnection` functions even show up with Get-Command?
Shouldn't the `FunctionsToExport` only export the functions that start with `My-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all my modules from the directory and opened ISE again to verify that the `New-SMOConnection` command is gone. Created then a new Module (My-HelpfullCommands) with only the `New-SMOConnection` in it. In all the other modules, I removed the `New-SMOConnection` function and copied them back into the modules directory.

Now the `New-SMOConnection` is declared only once and I can use it for all my modules.

Everything seems to work as expected.

Next I plan to add all my littel helper functions into the "My-HelpfullCommands" module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
Remove-Item -Path Function:New-SMOConnection
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that already. Your command gives me the  ObjectNotFound Error: `Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Function:\New-SMOConnection' because it does not exist`...  When I try the `Get-ChildItem -Path Function:\New-SMO*` it also doesn't list anything..   Is it possible that these functions are some "leftovers" from before I used the .psd1 files?

Comment: After I imported the modules manually, the command `New-SMOConnection` shows only once and is working.. But when I close the ISE window and open it again, the command shows twice up again. Any ideas?

Comment: probably because you have something in your profile. Check it using `psedit $profile`

Comment: Nice, thanks @Martin Brandl for that command. Did not know about that. But it doesn't look like there is something wrong in there... It shows 6 entries: `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`,  `ScriptBrowser.dll`,  `BestPractices.dll`,    `[ScriptExplorer.Views.MainView]`, `[BestPractices.Views.BestPracticesView]`and `VisibleVerticalAddOnTools.SelectedAddOnTool = $scriptBrowser` .. If I run it on the server, there is nothing to show, as the file does not exist.. I have the same behavior on my PC and on the server